# How to get rows in Google Sheets from repeating sections using Zapier

Tags: cognito-forms

I am using a zap to export the form entries to Google Sheets. It's all working as desired. However, for the repeating sections, I've understood that it will add the repeating values separated by commas. I would like these to be separate rows in the Google Sheets.

Will I need to do that part separately or will using tables give me that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Cognito does the right thing by generating repeating sections as an array in JSON.

Your repeating section array is nested inside the repeating section so Zapier flattens that out.  I.e., it's hard (impossible?) to reconstitute that in a Zapier Code action.  I thought of using Zapier Code because if you return an array an action fires for each element in the array.

If you're only wanting to JUST get at the repeating section you can use the "Pick off a Child Key " option when setting up the webhook and specify the name of your repeating section as the child key.  It should create an array output, one for each child.

I used Microsoft Azure LogicApps for my solution.

Start with a webhook (Request).  After you save that step it will show you a URL to post to.

Create a requestb.in.

Modify your Cognito form using the "Submission Settings" -> "Post JSON data to website" and paste in the URL for your requestb.in.  Submit the form and see how it comes across on requestb.in.  Copy the raw response.

Paste the JSON sample into the Request block where it says "Use sample payload to generate schema".

Now go back to Cognito and paste in the URL of the LogicApp Request block.

Add a "Parse JSON" block. Select the "row" inside the repeating sections and LogicApps will automatically add a "For Each" loop for the repeating section.    For the inside rows again use the "use sample payload to generate schema" and paste in just the JSON for the repeating section array e.g.,

{
  "properties": {
    "DayOfWeek": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "FromAddress": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ItemNumber": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}

Add a Google Sheets insert row action. You will get access to both the top-level fields as well as the nested detail fields.  So in effect you "denormalize" the records into Google Sheets.

It will probably take you longer to create a free Azure account than it will to create the LogicApp!

[image]